# C - rand() in loop

Tags: c

I'd like to fill an array of characters with random characters.

What I have right now:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 255        // Generate a random character
    }
```

Is there something shorter like maybe:

```c
memset(arr, rand() % 255, sizeof(arr));
```

Comment: For starters this loop for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++) is invalid.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Not necessarily given there's a hint the type is `char`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I did not pay attention to that the array is of characters.:)

Comment: `rand() % 255 ` -> `rand() % 255;`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For that `sizeof(char) == 1` this loop is valid?

Comment: The second example will fill the whole array with the same value.

Comment: @EsmaeelE given a `char arr[N];`, `sizeof(arr)` is equal to `N`.

Comment: Things can go awry though due to pointer decay. Which is why I bury a "necessarily" in my first comment.

Comment: @FredLarson, I know that but thanks for link. I want to ask Vlad [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415456/c-rand-in-loop#comment103173704_58415456) is the loop valid as always `sizeof(char)==1`

Comment: @EsmaeelE: I think it's valid as long as `arr` is actually a `char` *array* and not a pointer or an array of another type.

Comment: @FredLarson although that link works but specific link for sizeof in C is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof)

Comment: @EsmaeelE: Oops, quite right. Oddly, it appears my cppreference search didn't even give me the option for the C version.

Comment: There is shorter, call function `randomize(arr, sizeof(arr));`, you just need to write the function `randomize(unsigned char *, size_t)`.

Comment: ITYM `rand() % 256`, unless you don't want 255 to appear anywhere for some reason.  Actually, you really want `rand() % UCHAR_MAX` in a portable program.

Comment: @EsmaeelE, `sizeof (char)` is always 1, since sizes are measured in units of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something shorter like maybe:
>
> ```
> memset(arr, rand() % 255, sizeof(arr));
> ```

That would be a bit too short, as it would fill the array with multiple copies of the same value.

The former loop would be fine, assuming that you have declared `arr` as an array of `unsigned char` (note that `char` is signed in many environments, so that `rand() % 255` could overflow).

If you want something shorter, you could just wrap the loop into a function (a simple one, there's no need to [overly complicate](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0mJSgAbnm7pWtPtd) things).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

1. your array has a multiple of 4 elements
2. you want 7-bit randoms (0 to 127)
3. your `rand()` function produces numbers between `0x0` and `0x7fffffff`
4. you can safely convert from `char*` to `uint32_t*`

```
void fillrandom(char *dst, size_t len) {
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k += 4) {
        *(uint32_t*)(dst+k) = rand() & 0x7f7f7f7f; // fill 4 bytes at once
    }
}
```

Yes, too many assumptions!

https://ideone.com/7ILLp4